# Can we set dynamic value to Key attribute of RegistryKey element in WIX?

Tags: wix

I need to set Key attribute value at run time.

```
<RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="Software\ApplicationName">
```

I will get application name from the user. I want to append application name with default key.

For example: if the application name is test then key should be "Software\Test"

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved in 2 simple steps:

1. Declare your `<RegistryKey>` element like this:

   `<RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="Software\[APPLICATIONNAME]"> ... </RegistryKey>`
2. Save the user input to the `APPLICATIONNAME` property